# get objects that match a key value from a nested object that is quoted

Tags: json, jq

I have a list of JSON objects with this format

```
[
 {
    "uuid": "2e08c71c-56af-4c1d-9677-0aad7bf38536",
    "name": "img-s3",
    "summary": "",
    "retention_name": "month",
    "retention_uuid": "beae2f1a-10e9-4b53-b9b1-baf823624ff2",
    "expiry": 2678400,
    "schedule_name": "daily",
    "schedule_uuid": "baca1a64-b506-4789-83c8-653573f2b99f",
    "schedule_when": "daily 2am",
    "paused": false,
    "store_uuid": "d91fd7b6-4c39-4f73-aa44-8ec55f52da65",
    "store_name": "default",
    "store_plugin": "s3v8",
    "store_endpoint": "{\"access_key_id\":\"xxxx\",\"bucket\":\"images-c4\",\"s3_host\":\"s3.amazon.com\",\"secret_access_key\":\"yyy\",\"signature_version\":\"2\",\"skip_ssl_validation\":true}",
    "target_uuid": "991c7aa2-cdd3-4f90-bb28-1431c99f8fc8",
    "target_name": "sc-asd",
    "target_plugin": "mysql",
    "target_endpoint": "{\"mysql_database\":\"users\",\"mysql_host\":\"10.10.22.49\",\"mysql_password\":\"password\",\"mysql_port\":\"3306\",\"mysql_user\":\"user\"}",
    "agent": "127.0.0.1:3030"
}
...
]
```

I need to obtain only the objects using `storege_plugin: "s3v8"` and that in the "quoted" value object of `storage_endpoint` the key `signature_version` is `2`

To find the object having `storage_plugin: "s3v8"`, and `store_endpoing != null` I am using this:

```
$ command | jq '.[] | select(.store_plugin == "s3v8" and .store_endpoint != null)'
```

But the problem I have now is that the value of `store_endpoint` is quoted and I only need to get results based on the value of a key, in this case, `signature_value`

To test how to unquote and search for the value I am trying this:

```
$ echo "{\"access_key_id\":\"xxxx\",\"bucket\":\"images-c4\",\"s3_host\":\"s3.amazon.com\",\"secret_access_key\":\"yyy\",\"signature_version\":\"2\",\"skip_ssl_validation\":true}" \
| jq -r 'select(.signature_version == "2")'
{
  "access_key_id": "xxxx",
  "bucket": "images-c4",
  "s3_host": "s3.amazon.com",
  "secret_access_key": "yyy",
  "signature_version": "2",
  "skip_ssl_validation": true
}
```

But would like to know how could I "merge" this options so that I could get a list of objects that have a set of required keys but that depends on a nested key stored on a quoted object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `fromjson` construct on the nested JSON field as below. The [`fromjson`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) is *not* so well documented in the official documentation but it allows you to parse JSON texts into values for use in filters.

```
.[] | select((.store_plugin == "s3v8" and .store_endpoint != null) and (.store_endpoint | fromjson | .signature_version == "2") )
```

[jqplay.org - URL](https://jqplay.org/s/JTEvXsyTfl)